# Is this translation of the controversial Ashwameda Yagna Khanda correct?

Tags: vedas, translation

> O Mummy, Mummikins, little Mummy.
>
> No one is leading me (to matrimony).
>
> the bad little horse is sleeping.
>
> The adhvaryu says (TS):
>
> In the heavenly world be you two completely covered.
>
> The queen says:
>
> I will urge on the impregnator, you will urge on the impregnator;
>
> let the two of us together stretch out our four legs.
>
> The adhvaryu says:
>
> Let the stallion, semen-producer, produce semen,
>
> Bring the penis into the two thighs,
>
> drive along the erect and unctuous one
>
> which is women's living enjoyment,
>
> which is their hole-runner,
>
> women's dear secret (pleasure)
>
> which has hit the sardigrdi (clitoris?)
>
> in their black(haired) mark.

Taittiriya Samhita 7.4.19

Comment: You should have also posted or atleast given the  link to original Sanskrit text.

Comment: Second time coming across this weirdo sex stuffs with the queen and the poor horse. Plz let this be interpolations misunderstandings type of thing cause what on earth 

Comment: Obvious that it is symbolic from the words" in the heavenly world be you two completely covered." From reading the Rigveda and understanding those parts it is clear that Indra ( symbolised by Surya, Vaja, or the Ashva horse) fertilises cloud and causes rain to fall on Earth. Rain is water giver of life. Those with spiritual approach will see it immediately. Rigveda is theirs. The unclean will savour the steamy flavour, let them cook.

Comment: @ajitdas Then why do the şrāuta-sūtrá-s, texts which prescribe real ritual action have these: 
ĀpŞS XX. 18.4 prajananena prajananam saṁdhāya
Putting (its) generative organ together with (her) generative organ.
KŞS XX.6.16 aśvaśiśnam upasthe kurute
(The Mahiṣī) takes the penis of the horse in her lap.
VārŞS III.4.4.15 sam̐hitaprajananayoḥ
When their two generative organs have been put together. . .
ŞB XIII.5.2.2 áśvasya śiśnaṁ máhiṣy úpasthe nídhatte 
The Mahiṣī puts the penis of the horse in her lap